# How to connect to sqlite database from Windows Runtime Component which is for running Background tasks

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, background-process

I am having trouble connecting to sqlite database from Windows Runtime Component which is for running Background tasks..
I am including all the dll required the same way I added for the main project..
But it doesn’t work..
Shows some 200 errors..
I followed this post :https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/104
But still I get errors..
2  such errors are:

Error      2              Windows Runtime class 'SQLite.SQLiteException' has an invalid base type 'System.Exception'. Exporting custom exception types is not allowed.                D:\MCM-22-Jan-2013\CCM\TileBackground\SQLite.cs   46           15           TileBackground

Error      92           Type 'SQLite.TableMapping.Column' is a nested type.  Nested types cannot be exported to the Windows Runtime.             D:\MCM-22-Jan-2013\CCM\TileBackground\SQLite.cs 1390       16                TileBackground

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this problem today, and with the help of https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/104 I'm able to solve it. Basically you have 2 things to do after sqlite-net of nuget is setup.

1. You need to change all `public` of class definition (5th column) to `internal`, for SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs
2. You need to change namespace `SQLite` to whatever namespace your C# project is using.

This way, this wrapper become part of your C# component / Windows Runtime Component, and it's not exported.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Sqlite in a background task successfully. I have the sqlite-net source files in a regular Windows Store dll. Both my main app and my background task projects need to access the same sqlite db, so they both reference this dll.

It seems that by structuring the source code this way, that I (unintentionally) avoided the issue you are seeing. Note that I did not have to tweak the Sqlite-net source files to work around the issue.